# Add colspan to last cell of dynamic table row if row has fewer columns

Tags: jquery, html-table, dynamic-tables

Maybe this has been asked before, but my many google searches aren't pulling up my need...

I have a table that is created dynamically. In it contains rows that have 4 columns and rows that have 3 columns. What I want to do is align the last cell of rows with 3 columns to the far right of the table. I think the best way is to add a colspan="2"  to the last column of a 3 column row.

So my question is, how can I get the greatest number of columns in a table, and add a colspan to the last cell of a row that contains fewer columns to fill up that balance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set `colspan`s for individual cells.  Just use a large number for the last cell of *every* row.  It won't add any extra space to the table.

In this Snippet, click the **Fill** button to set the `colspan` in the last cell in each row to 999:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('table tr').find('td:last').attr('colspan',999);
});
```

```css
table {
  font: 14px verdana;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0.2em;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Fill</button>
<table>
  <tr><td>Lorem <td>ipsum <td>dolor <td>sit
  <tr><td>amet, <td>consectetur <td>adipiscing <td>elit, <td>sed <td>do
  <tr><td>eiusmod <td>tempor <td>incididunt <td>ut <td>labore
  <tr><td>et <td>dolore <td>magna
  <tr><td>aliqua.
</table>
```

Comment: That's pretty genius! I never knew you could do that :)

Comment: Absolutely. I had no idea either. Way to think outside the box. That works perfectly for me. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is to create dynamic table.

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/ncfs796q/3/)

If your question is about finding the column count of  the row, then this is the command.

```
$("#columnCount").append($("#setTable tr:eq(1) td").length);
```

Hope i understood your question. If you want to display 3 and 4 columns in one table itself, then the code need to be modified as

[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/buuq4dqo/).

Hope your question is answered.

Comment: This does not really address the issue in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's not just finding out the amount of cells in the row, it was about matching the colspan to rows with fewer cells to the larger rows. Rick's answer above solves that issue. Thanks again!